# Understanding Django initial_data fixture

Tags: django, django-fixtures

### Question

- Why does Django automatically load the `initial_data.json` fixture when it's located inside the project directory but not located in one of the three specified locations that Django searches for fixtures?

### Configuration Information

1. I have not set the `FIXTURE_DIRS` setting in settings.py
2. Django 1.2.1

### Django's Documentation Regarding Fixture Locations

The [What's a "Fixture"](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#what-s-a-fixture) section of Django's [django-admin.py and manage.py](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/) documentation states:

> Django will search in three locations for fixtures:
>
> 1. In the fixtures directory of every installed application
> 2. In any directory named in the FIXTURE_DIRS setting
> 3. In the literal path named by the fixture
>
> Django will load any and all fixtures it finds in these locations that match the provided fixture names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

initial_data is actually behaviour belonging to [syncdb](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/?from=olddocs#syncdb). What you are citing is the default places loaddata will look for when queried. initial_data.json is detected by the syncdb option and passed to loaddata. I agree it's a bit confusing, but you are actually mixing general fixture loading behaviour (loaddata) with automatic fixture loading behaviour (syncdb).

Hope this helps.